# Problems with computed var after mapping and adding new elements to observableArray

Tags: knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to create within knockout mapping some computed variables. The problem is when adding new elements to the children's children after the mapping, my computed variables don't update with new elements added to the observableArray

Please could you help?

Here is the code, also attached a jsFiddle

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/r3pasftb/18/

```
var data = {id: 45, Name: "Whatever Name", 
Stages: [{stageID: 1, StageName: "Stage1", Team: [{Name: "Team1", FeesAllocated: 500}, {Name: "Team2", FeesAllocated: 200}]}, {stageID: 1, StageName: "Stage1", Team: []}]};

mappingTeam = function(options){
var teamSelf = options != null ? options : this;
teamSelf.Name = ko.observable(options != null ? options.Name : 0);
teamSelf.FeesAllocated = ko.observable(options != null ? options.FeesAllocated : 0);
return teamSelf;
};

mappingStages = function(options){
    var stageSelf = options != null ? options : this;

  stageSelf.StageID = ko.observable(options != null ? options.StageID : 0);
  stageSelf.StageName = ko.observable(options != null ? options.StageName : 0);
  stageSelf.Team = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(stageSelf.Team, mappingTeam ));


  stageSelf.Length = ko.computed(function(){
        return stageSelf.Team().length;
  });

  //I need this value to be updated, but do nothing with new elements created after the mapping
  stageSelf.TotalStageFees = ko.computed(function(){
        var total = 0;

      ko.utils.arrayForEach(stageSelf.Team(), function (team) {
                total += team.FeesAllocated();
            });
            return total;
  });

  return stageSelf;
};

var mappingOptions = {

        create: function (options) {
            return new function () {
                var self = options.data;

               //Here map Stage Array
                self.Stages = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Stages, mappingStages ));

                ko.mapping.fromJS(self, {}, this);
            };
        }
    };

    //Map my object with child and subchild
    var self = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
    console.log(self.Stages()[0].TotalStageFees())
    console.log(self.Stages()[0].Length())

    //Add new TeamMember to first Stage
    self.Stages()[0].Team.push(new mappingTeam({Name: "Team3", FeesAllocated: 50}));

    //As you see, non TotalStageFees or Lenght are updated
    console.log(self.Stages()[0].TotalStageFees())
    console.log(self.Stages()[0].Team())
    console.log(self.Stages()[0].Length())
```